# No window decoration around nautilus windows in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, nautilus

I updated my Ubuntu and after window boarders for nautilus has been disappeared and the menu items that are on the unity top bar does not work. Menus are still there but you cannot click on them but shortcut strokes still functioning. I checked some of the solutions from internet but none of them worked. Any suggestion or further comment is appreciated?

Here Is the current state of nautilus window:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems not to be a "feature" question, but a "profile" topic: when running nautilus as root (sudo nautilus or gksu nautilus in a terminal window), the top bar is back there, but on the root-nautilus session only. If you quit all nautilus (nautilus -q) and run a root-nautilus and then return to "normal" nautilus, the top bar is missing again.

Answer (score 0):

On another machine I have, the windows are exactly like that in File Manager - `nautilus`version `3.10.1`. This does not seem to be a problem in versions of Nautilus like `3.8.2`.

The easiest solution I found was to use [Nemo](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html) instead - which is the official file manager for Cinnamon, and is based on an earlier release of Nautilus. It is pretty much the same, but works better, still has dual pane etc:

[ [image: nemo]

Another method would be to downgrade the nautilus package if you still can - there is a guide on that [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/) - you should be able to do this if you run this an find older versions:

```
apt-cache showpkg packagename
```

You can find the current version using

```
dpkg -l nautilus
```

And install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install PACKAGE=VERSION
```

You can get the version from the aboe `apt-cache` command/

If you can't downgrade it, you will probably have to download the deb file [from here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/saucy/main/base/nautilus) or somewhere, and manually install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE.deb
```

**After doing either method of downgrading it, you will need to lock the version of the package so it is not automatically updated.** You can do this with [Synaptic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/):

[image: synaptic]

Or with this command:

```
sudo echo “PACKAGE hold” | sudo dpkg –set-selections
```

Where `PACKAGE` = `nautilus`.